# How to install firebase properly?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I am working on a login system in vue, this is my code for now:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" v-model="email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" v-model="password" />
    <button>Login</button>
    <p>Need an account?<router-link to="/signup">Sign Up</router-link></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
  name: "Login",
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    Login() {
      // Log the user in
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(
          (user) => {
            console.log(user.data);
          },
          (err) => {
            alert(err);
          }
        );
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The problem is that I get an error when I try to run it, this is the error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* firebase in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/views/Login.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save firebase
```

I tried installing firebase a couple of times, but I keep getting the same error.

If anyone knows a solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install firebase properly, you have to change the version:

```
npm remove firebase
npm add firebase@^8.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, what command are you running to install Firebase? The error says to use `npm install --save firebase`, are you using that command? Try the command`npm install Firebase` to try install Firebase.  Are you using "Cloud Shell" to deploy your code?

I used the following documentation to learn about the basics of Firebase [1}

[1} https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

and this lab is also very useful [2]

[1] https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#0